# Regex for name with space in HTML5

Tags: php, regex, html, web

I tried below pattern for Name field in HTML5, but everytime I am getting error :- "Please match the requested format"

Apart from above pattern, I also gave different pattern like :-
a) pattern="/^[A-Za-z\s]+$/"
b) pattern="/^[A-Za-z]\s[A-Za-z]+$/"

All the three pattern are not working. What I want is simple Firstname Lastname like "Harry Potter".
Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first name can only be 1 char? ;) You need to get rid of `/` (this is only needed for defining a regex in JavaScript). Also `^` and `$` are not needed in the pattern attribute as they are enforced anyway.

Comment: Remove the backslashes. Use `pattern="[A-Za-z]+\s[A-Za-z]+"` as anchors are redundant here.

Comment: Names don't work like that! http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew — Those are forward slashes

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove leading and trailing slashes from your pattern because in JavaScript they're indicate that string is actually a regular expression, but in html attribute it is already known to be a regular expression.

Pattern itself will depend on what kind of names you want to accept, your expression will not accept non-latin names, but there is a lot of people with such names. Basically if you want to check for existence of at least 2 words (since name can contain more then 2 words). For example you can use this `pattern="\D\S+(\s+\D\S+)+"` that will check for existence for at least 2 words separated by whitespace and each word should not start with a digit.